# Sending a file with the correct Content-Type instead of application/octet-stream

Tags: go

I have a function that sends a file to a URL with the "Content-type" of the file set to application/octet-stream. I've tried various methods, but none of them have achieved the desired effect. How can I modify the function to ensure that the file is received in a different format on another server?

```
func (s *FileService)SentFileToCreate(ctx context.Context, userUUID string, form *multipart.Form) (*models.File, error) {
    var Fileresult = &models.File{}
    now := time.Now()

    textValue := form.Value["text"][0]
    files := form.File["files"]

    id, _ := s.repo.GetUserIdByUuid(ctx, userUUID)
    Fileresult.Text = textValue
    Fileresult.CreatedStamp = &now
    Fileresult.AuthorID = id

    var mediaL []*models.File

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    url := "http://0.0.0.0:9090/api/v1/file/upload"

    for _, file := range files {
        media := &models.File{
            FileName:    file.Filename,
            ContentType: file.Header.Get("Content-Type"),
        }
        mediaL = append(mediaL, media)

        part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("files", file.Filename)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        fileContent, err := file.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        defer fileContent.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(part, fileContent)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        fileHeader := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
        for key, values := range file.Header {
            fileHeader[key] = values
        }

        err = sendFileToURL(url, &multipart.FileHeader{
            Filename: file.Filename,
            Header:   fileHeader,
        })
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        }
    }

    err := writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("Status:", resp.Status)

    return s.repo.SaveFile(ctx, Fileresult)
}

func sendFileToURL(url string, fileHeader *multipart.FileHeader) error {
    file, err := fileHeader.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", fileHeader.Header.Get("Content-Type"))

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("HTTP Status Code:", response.StatusCode)

    return nil
}
```

I've explored different approaches to modify it, but unfortunately, none of them has produced the desired effect. I'm seeking guidance on how to adjust the function to ensure that the file is received in a different format on another server. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!